# How to find the closest value in a list where x > value for every value in a numpy array without looping

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

For a scalar, let's say I have the following levels

```
levels_ = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

and the function

```
import numpy as np

def find_level(x, levels):
    levels = np.asarray(levels)
    if x <= levels.min() or x >= levels.max():
        idx = (np.abs(levels - x)).argmin()
    else:
        idx = np.argmax(levels > x) - 1
    return levels[idx]
```

The function will return the nearest value where x>value from the ordered values of the levels and within the lower and upper boundaries as well.

```
find_level(x=0.5, levels=levels_) # will return 5
find_level(x=7.01, levels=levels_) # will return 7
find_level(x=7.50, levels=levels_) # will return 7
find_level(x=7.99, levels=levels_) # will return 7
find_level(x=15, levels=levels_) # will return 10
```

I would like to pass an array x of any size and obtain an array of the same size with the same computation for every value of the array. For example, with the following input:

```
x_ = np.array([[0.5, 7.01, 7.50, 7.99, 15],
               [20, 30, 6.26, 5.01, 6.54]])
```

, the function `find_level_multi(x=x_, levels=levels_)` would the return the following output:

```
np.array([[5, 7, 7, 7, 10],
          [10, 10, 6, 5, 6]])
```

I could loop through every row and column and use the function `find_level(x, levels)` but it would be extremly slow for a large array so I am looking for a function that could accomplish the same task in less time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to find the indices where the elements in `x` should be inserted into `levels`, maintaining the order. Assumes `levels` is sorted. This solution also works with a scalar or (multi-dimensional) array argument for `x`:

```
import numpy as np

def find_level(x, levels):
    """ this assumes levels is sorted """
    levels = np.asanyarray(levels)
    indices = np.searchsorted(levels, np.floor(x))
    indices = np.clip(indices, 0, len(levels) - 1) # clip out-of-bounds index
    return levels[indices]
```

Testing it:

```
levels_ = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

find_level(x=0.5, levels=levels_) # 5
find_level(x=7.01, levels=levels_) # 7
find_level(x=7.50, levels=levels_) # 7
find_level(x=7.99, levels=levels_) # 7
find_level(x=15, levels=levels_) # 10

x_ = np.array([[0.5, 7.01, 7.50, 7.99, 15],
           [20, 30, 6.26, 5.01, 6.54]])
find_level(x_, levels_)
# array([[ 5,  7,  7,  7, 10],
#        [10, 10,  6,  5,  6]])
```

Comment: There's no need for `take`. Indexing as `levels[index]` works just fine. The output is the same shape as the index.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Only if I use `levels = np.asarray(levels)` first. I will edit.

Comment: `take` will apply `asanyarray` for you whether you like it or not anyway.

Comment: You may want to update the prose as well, and use `asanyarray` rather than `asarray`. It's more forgiving of things like pandas dataframes.

Comment: Sure, but my original solution would not work with the indexing approach because `levels` was not necessarily an array (it is a list in the OP).

Comment: I slightly modified the function and removed the floor in the second line to handle floats in the levels array. Otherwise, the output was the closest integer.

indices = np.searchsorted(a=levels, v=x, side='right') - 1

For example, without the tweak, this call 

find_level(x=np.array([0.5, 4.9, 5.0, 5.01, 6.99, 7.0, 7.51, 7.99, 9.99, 10.0, 10.01, 15]),
            levels=[5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8, 8.5, 9, 9.5, 10])

returns

np.array([ 5,  5,  5,  5,  6,  7,  7,  7,  9, 10, 10, 10])

With the tweak, it returns

np.array([ 5,  5,  5,  5,  6.5,  7,  7.5,  7.5,  9.5, 10, 10, 10])

Answer (score 1):

You can use broadcasting to build an implicit 3D array from the 2D and perform an `np.argmax` reduction on one axis. To vectorize the condition, you can use `np.select`. Here is the resulting vectorized implementation:

```py
def find_level(x, levels):
    levels = np.asarray(levels)
    minIdx = levels.argmin()
    maxIdx = levels.argmax()
    idx = np.argmax(levels[:,None,None] > x[None, :,:], axis=0) - 1
    idx = np.select([x <= levels[minIdx], x >= levels[maxIdx], True], [minIdx, maxIdx, idx])
    return levels[idx]
```

Here is an example:

```py
x_ = np.array([[0.5, 7.01, 7.50, 7.99, 15],
               [20, 30, 6.26, 5.01, 6.54]])
levels_ = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
result = find_level(x_, levels_)
print(result)
```

Here is the result on the provided input:

```
[[ 5  7  7  7 10]
 [10 10  6  5  6]]
```

Note that iterating over all the levels for each cell is probably not the most efficient method if the number of levels is huge.

Comment: This is an unnecessarily long way to do it. `searchsorted` is a much better solution here, especially for larger arrays.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I agree. Hence the final note in the answer. `searchsorted` may not be significantly faster for very short array. Moreover, `levels` should be sorted before (or at least assumed to be). Note that there are faster solution than `searchsorted`, but these one make assumptions on the content of `levels`.